# JS / JQuery - Check All Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a photo gallery. Underneath each photo is a checkbox, with the ID containing a prefix of 'checkbox_', followed by the photo ID.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_<%=photoID%>" name="photos">
```

When I check a 'selectAll' checkbox, like this one:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggleAll" name="toggleAll" onclick="toggleAll()">
```

I want to check/uncheck all checkboxes that have the name 'photos', so I have this function that ***should*** do that... but it doesn't:

```
function toggleAll() {
if (document.getElementById('toggleAll').checked == true)
        {
        $('.photoBlob').animate({backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,102,204,0.5)'}, 500);
        $('.photoBlob').animate({backgroundColor: 'rgba(204,204,204,1)'}, 1500);
        document.getElementByName('photos').checked = true;
        }
else
        {
        $('.photoBlob').animate({backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'}, 1000);
        document.getElementByName('photos').checked = false;
        }
}
```

The rest of the function works okay, it animates the background colors of the containing DIV (#photoBlob) when the toggleALL() function is called. But, I really can't get all the checkboxes to check and I have tried so many different variations!

Can anybody see what I am doing wrong? The problem lies with these two lines:

```
document.getElementByName('photos').checked = true;
document.getElementByName('photos').checked = false;
```

Any suggestions gratefully received...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this,
don't use same name for several check boxes because the name shroud be unique. Instead of use  the class.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_<%=photoID%>" class="photos">
```

an the jquery,

```
$('#toggleAll').click(function(){
    var checked =$(this).attr('checked');
    $('.photos').attr('checked', checked);

}
```

Comment: `checked` is a property, not an attribute.

Comment: @Matt: It is an attribute as well: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-30233917

Comment: How would you implement your code into the toggle function? That might be a better answer.

Comment: I did this for uncheck: $('.photos').attr('checked','');

Comment: @FelixKling JQuery's preferred usage is to treat it as a property: http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/10/jquery-1-6-1-rc-1-released/

Comment: @Matt: Actually I posted the wrong link. This is more correct: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/input#Attributes. And no matter what is jQuery's preferred usage, it's still an attribute ;)

Comment: Why `var checked =$(this).attr('checked');` ? Why not `this.checked` ? This is why old school JS devs hate JQuery devs you know lol.

Comment: @FelixKling `prop()` seems to be slightly faster, about 10% faster in FF and 20% faster in Chrome in the benchmark provided: http://jsperf.com/attr-vs-prop -- my point being regardless of the DOM specs, JQuery has preferred usage apparently because it has different logic in place.

Comment: @Matt: That's ok. I would prefer `.prop` as well. I just wanted to point out that your statement, `checked` being not an attribute, is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#toggleAll').click(function(){
    $(':checkbox[name="photos"]').prop('checked',this.checked);
});
```

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uNeX2/

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing an "s" in getElementByTagName. Try `getElementsByTagName`.

This might also work:

```
$("#toggleAll").click(function() {<br/>
    $("input[name='photos']").attr("checked",!!$(this).attr("checked"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

well, since you said, you have multiple checkboxes with the name 'photos', selecting only one element by using the function getElementByName, can't be ur choice of game. Using jQuery simplifies the task your trying to do;

```
$("input[name=photos]").each(function(elem){
    elem.checked=true;
}
```

or simpler;

```
$("input[name=photos]").attr('checked','checked');
```

its its js-only, youd need to select all input elements via getElementsByTagName and then filter out the ones that don't comply with having a name of 'photos'.. and then do your task.

Comment: Yet again, `checked` is a property, not an attribute.

Comment: @MattAnderson yes, you are correct. But just because jQuerys function is called attr, it doesn't mean, attr cant set a property. Or do you know a jQuery function called prop? ;) looking at the internals of javascript, a property or attribute is pretty much the same -> its a key within an object. Set it.

Comment: @MattAnderson ouh.. damn.. quite a fail from my side ;) I am not familiar with jQuery1.6, 'cause I stopped using it since 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example using jQuery:

html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="all" >
<input type="checkbox" name="photo" >
<input type="checkbox" name="photo" >
<input type="checkbox" name="photo" >
<input type="checkbox" name="photo" >
```

js

```
$('#all').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('checked') == undefined) {
        $('input[name=photo]').removeAttr('checked');        
    }
    else {
        $('input[name=photo]').attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/b8Y9t/3/

Comment: Again, `checked` is a property, not an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
$('.photos:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no function called getElementByName. Did you have a javascript-error?   I think it should be [getElementsByName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp). This returns a list with elements. That means you have to loop trough it to check all checkboxes.

BTW I think it is not correct to use a name called 'photos' for a checkbox, since a checkbox is a single object and does not display a photo itself. I would name it 'photoCheckbox' or 'cbPhoto' to clearify it is a checkbox.

```
var checkboxList = getElementsByName('photoCheckbox'); // returns list with checkboxes with name 'photoCheckbox'
if (checkboxList)
{
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxList.length; i++)
  {
    var checkbox = checkboxList[i];
    checkbox.checked = false;
  }
}
```

Thats how the getElementsByName function works. So if you would evaluate this method, you would say this is unnecessary since you are already using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)? I would simplify the code of the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleAll(this)" />
```

The new toggleAll function looks like this:

```
 function toggleAll(checkbox)
 {
    if (checkbox.checked)
    {
       $('.photoBlob').animate({backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,102,204,0.5)'}, 500);
       $('.photoBlob').animate({backgroundColor: 'rgba(204,204,204,1)'}, 1500); // btw why 2 animations on the same elements..?

       $('input[name="photos"]').prop("checked", true);
    }
    else
    {
       $('.photoBlob').animate({backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'}, 1000);

       $('input[name="photos"]').prop("checked", false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// jquery check all or uncheck all

$('.checkall').click(function(){    

  var status = 'false';

  status = $('.checkall').is(":checked");

  //alert ('status is ' + status);  // you should see true or false     

  $('.metacheckbox').each( function() {

   $(this).attr('checked', status);

  });

});


<input class="checkall" type="checkbox" />Check/UnCheck All

<input class="metacheckbox" type="checkbox" id='checkboxone' name="checkboxone" value="Y" /> 

<input class="metacheckbox" type="checkbox" id='checkboxtwo' name="checkboxtwo" value="Y" /> 

<input class="metacheckbox" type="checkbox" id='checkboxthree' name="checkboxthree" value="Y" /> 

this worked for me.
```